# Insert "beforeend" with htmx and server-sent events?

Tags: server-sent-events, htmx

I'm using htmx 1.6.1 and I'm experimenting with the [server-sent events](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-sse/) support. I'm implementing a simple chat, and when a user posts a message I want this message to be sent to all chat participants. Thus when I receive a new message on the server I convert it into an HTML fragment and send it over the SSE connection to each client. For example, when the chat page loads it returns this HTML with all the chat messages:

```
<ul hx-sse="connect:/chat" ...>
 <li>john: Chat message 1</li>
 <li>jane: Chat message 2</li>
</ul>
```

Now if "john" posts another message, like "hello", to some resource
then I want to send `<li>john: hello</li>` over SSE to each client resulting in this HTML:

```
<ul hx-sse="connect:/chat" ...>
 <li>john: Chat message 1</li>
 <li>jane: Chat message 2</li>
 <li>john: hello</li>
</ul>
```

But I don't know how to do this. I've managed to trigger a GET to the server *after* the SSE event is received by the client to fetch the entire "ul" again, but this is *not* what I want to do. (What I think) I want to do is to insert the content of the SSE event "beforeend" of the "ul" tag, *without* making an additional request to the server.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is a typo in the last html section. If John send "hello", I guess that the other participants want to see "hello".

Comment: I have not worked with SSE up to now. But maybe this helps: https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/

Comment: in your profile, the link to your swedish page is broken: https://stackoverflow.com/users/398441/johan

Comment: I've corrected the type now, thanks!

Comment: @Johan Can you please show the backend part, so we can see what exactly do you send? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer to this question:
[https://stacko...sent-event-sse-with-htmx-and-append-to-a-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74024224/listen-for-server-sent-event-sse-with-htmx-and-append-to-a-table)
It's about inserting a new row in a table. In short: the server sends json. The client uses a template to insert the json into the table as a row.

If you change your mind and the server only sends an id and the HTML to be inserted is to be generated on the server side and retrieved with a get request, then see the answer to this question
[https://stacko...mx-get-from-an-sse-event-which-itself-triggers-the-hx-get-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73552671/how-to-get-url-for-htmx-get-from-an-sse-event-which-itself-triggers-the-hx-get-c)