# How to get url for htmx get from an SSE event which itself triggers the hx-get call?

Tags: django, django-channels, htmx

I am using django with django-channels and htmx.

In certain cases, my django views will send an SSE event to a user subscribed to the relevant channel, like a notification for example. Some of those events (depending on event name) needs to trigger a modal pop-up (like a rating modal after an e-commerce order or service completes).

I have implemented the requirements of the server-side event and data generation. I want to use the htmx sse extension on the frontend (django template).

My problem is, I want to get an event, let's say `order_complete`, and use that to trigger an `hx-get` call to a particular url which will be sent by the sse event. That `hx-get`'s response will then be placed in the placeholder where modal view logic exists. I can get the event and trigger the get request as described in the htmx sse extension docs, but I don't know how to get the url to put in the hx-get.

I have very little knowledge of JavaScript and not all that much more on htmx. I've looked at out of band swaps but I'm not sure if that's what I need.

I'd appreciate any opinion or suggestions for proceeding including a non-htmx solution if it's better performing or easier.

Thank you.

Comment: Would it be sufficient if just passing url-parameters with sse, appending them to the (fixed) url and then execute hx-get?

Comment: It would be great if I could get the constructed url but I can get around to accepting params, too, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append parameters to a (fixed) url.

In a client side javascript handle the sseMessage event.

```js
    document.body.addEventListener('htmx:sseMessage', function (evt) {

        //* check if this event is the one you want to use
        if (evt.detail.type !== "order_complete") {
            return;
        }

        //* If a JSON string was sent, leave it as it is 
        //evt.detail.elt.setAttribute("hx-vals", evt.detail.data);

        //* if not
        var msg = {};
        msg.orderId = evt.detail.data;   
        evt.detail.elt.setAttribute("hx-vals", JSON.stringify(msg));
    });
```

see  https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-vals/

resulting url if evt.detail.data was 123:

```
/orders/showmodal?orderId=123
```

the html:

```html
    <div hx-ext="sse" sse-connect="/sse-something">
        <div hx-get="/orders/showmodal"
                hx-trigger="sse:order_complete"
                hx-swap="innerHTML"
                hx-target="#idModalPlaceholder">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Update**
You can also use an event listener just for **order_complete**.

```js
    document.body.addEventListener('sse:order_complete', function (evt) {

        //* If a JSON string was sent, leave it as it is 
        //evt.detail.elt.setAttribute("hx-vals", evt.detail.data);

        //* if not
        var msg = {};
        msg.orderId = evt.detail.data;   
        evt.detail.elt.setAttribute("hx-vals", JSON.stringify(msg));
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. That should solve my problem. On a side note, there's no way to construct the url with kwargs in the url itself, right? For example, `orders/<pk>/modal` or something like that?

Comment: I tried it. Changing the hx-get attribute had no effect.