# Listen for server sent event (SSE) with HTMX and append to a table

Tags: htmx

I made a simple Go backend that renders an html table (from a SQLite database).
In the same backend i have an `/updates` endpoint with server sent events (SSE) when a new row is added to the database.

I want to use htmx to listen for events and then **add a row to the table**.

What is the right pattern to do this?
I've read https://htmx.org/extensions/server-sent-events/

the example here is to trigger a GET when an event arrives:

```html
<div hx-ext="sse" sse-connect="/updates">
  <div hx-get="/table" hx-trigger="sse:rowadded">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

In this way I request the entire table at every update.
How could I add only a single row to the existent rendered table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with client side templates.
See  https://htmx.org/extensions/client-side-templates/

Example:

```html
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Manufacturer
                </th>
                <th>
                    Model
                </th>
                <th>
                    Power (KW)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="idTableBody">
            <tr id="ModelId_250">
                <td>Husqvarna</td>
                <td>701 Supermoto</td>
                <td>55</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In this example **mustache** is used as templating engine.

```html
    <div hx-ext="client-side-templates">
        <div hx-ext="sse" sse-connect="/sse-motorbikes">
            <div sse-swap="new_bike"
                 hx-swap="afterbegin"
                 hx-target="#idTableBody"
                 mustache-template="idTemplateInsertModel">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note: EventName is *new_bike*

Here is the template:

```
<template id="idTemplateInsertModel">
    <tr id="modelId_{{modelId}}">
        <td>
            {{manufacturer}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{model}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{power}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

With this sse event

```
type: "new_bike"
data:'{"modelId":208,"manufacturer":"Honda","model":"CRF 1100 L Africa Twin","power":75}'
```

this row will be inserted into the table body

```html
    <tr id="modelId_208">
        <td>Honda</td>
        <td>CRF 1100 L Africa Twin</td>
        <td>75</td>
    </tr>
```

### Update

If you want to use a GET request to fetch the new row from the server, you can pass the data sent with the sse event (e.g. an id) to the request.
Check out the answer to this question.
[https://stacko...how-to-get-url-for-htmx-get-from-an-sse-event-which-itself-triggers-the-hx-get-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73552671/how-to-get-url-for-htmx-get-from-an-sse-event-which-itself-triggers-the-hx-get-c)